# feature selection after extraction process

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I read that it is recommended to use `feature selection` after `feature extraction` process.

But there is something missing in all the posts I read:

- Suppose we have 50 features.
- Suppose we use feature extraction and we got 3 new extraction features

2 questions:

1. Do we need to run the `feature selection` on:

   - The 3 extracted features ?
     or
   - total 53 features (base 50 features + 3 extracted features) ?
2. Suppose we run feature selection on the result of feature extraction and not all the new extracted features where chosen (i.e 2 out of 3) by feature selection algorithm, 
   it seems that the output of feature extraction was not good enough if we can drop one of the 'new' dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typically, all of them unless you have a prior belief.
2. There are dozens of feature selection methods. Each has its own power and they possibly won't agree completely. So, not being chosen doesn't seem that the new features are not expressive. But, if most selection algorithms don't prefer your new features over the older ones, then it's a signal of course.